# Rollback for doubly nested transaction bypasses savepoint

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

It's not exactly as the title says, but close to. Consider these Spring beans:

```
@Bean
class BeanA {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = EvilException.class)
    public void methodA() {
        /* ... some actions */
        if (condition) {
            throw new EvilException();
        }
    }
}

@Bean
class BeanB {
    @Autowired private BeanA beanA;
    final int MAX_TRIES = 3;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public void methodB() {
        // prepare to call Bean A
        try {
            beanA.methodA();
            /* maybe do some more things */
        }
        catch (EvilException e) {
           /* recover from evil */
        }
    }
}

@Bean
class MainWorkerBean {
    @Autowired private BeanB beanB;
    @Autowired private OtherBean otherBean;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void doSomeWork() {
        beanB.methodB();
        otherBean.doSomeWork();
    }
}
```

**Important note**: I'm using JDBC transaction manager that supports savepoints.

What I'm expecting this to do is, when `EvilException` is thrown, the transaction of the `BeanA` is rolled back, which with this setup happens to be the savepoint created by starting `methodB`. However, this appears to not be the case.

When going over with debugging tools, what I'm seeing is this:

1. When `doSomeWork` of `MainWorkerBean` starts, new transaction is created
2. When `methodB` starts, transaction manager properly initializes a savepoint and hands it to `TransactionInterceptor`
3. When `methodA` starts, transaction manager sees `Propagation.REQUIRED` again, and hands out a clean reference to the actual JDBC transaction again, that has no knowledge of the savepoint

This means that when exception is thrown, `TransactionStatus::hasSavepoint` return `false`, which leads to roll back of the whole global transaction, so recovery and further steps are as good as lost, but my actual code has no knowledge of the rollback (since I've written recovery for it).

For now, I can't consider changing `BeanA`'s transaction to `Propagation.NESTED`. Admittedly, looks like it's going to allow me to have the more local rollback, but it's going to be too local, because as I understand it, Spring then will have two savepoints, and only roll back the `BeanA` savepoint, not `BeanB` one, as I'd like.

Is there anything else I'm missing, such as a configuration option, that would make internal transaction with `Propagation.REQUIRED` consider that it is running inside a savepoint, and roll back to savepoint, not the whole thing?

Right now we're using Spring 4.3.24, but I already crawled through their code and can't spot any relevant changes, so I don't think upgrading will help me.

Comment: Yes, I have a test that confirms this behavior - it also allowed me to go over the whole thing with debugger, which is why I have the point about handing out the `TransactionStatus` object that is inside a savepoint, but still behaves like it's not in one, and rolls back entire tx. No, I can't change tx of `methodA`, because it's not the only place where it's called from, and in those places it's the correct policy to have. Switching to `MANDATORY` doesn't change anything, in this case (because of `doSomeWork()`, tx will exist), but will break other cases by now throwing an exception.

Comment: When `methodA` does the rollback, I'm supposed to recover internal state of the `BeanB`, but still should be able to commit whatever the `OtherBean::doSomeWork` does after the fact. The entire tx is rolled back IFF `OtherBean` rolls back. Right now, this is not what's happening - when `BeanB` rolls back, `OtherBean::doSomeWork` is also rolled back. You're right saying that  in this example properties of `methodA()` do not matter - but they matter in overal system, since `methodA` is also called on its own from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in this bug ticket: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/11234

For spring versions < 5.0, in the situation described, the global transaction is set to 'rollback-only'.

> In this transaction I am processing several tasks. If an error should occur during a single task, I do not want the whole transaction to be rolled back, therefore I wrap the task processing in another transaction boundary with a propagation of PROPAGATION_NESTED.
>
> The problem comes when, during task processing, calls are made to existing service methods defined with a transaction boundary of PROPAGATION_REQUIRED. Any runtime exceptions thrown from these methods cause the underlying connection to be marked as rollback-only, rather than respecting the current parent transaction nested propagation.
>
> [...]
>
> As of Spring Framework 5.0, nested transactions resolve their rollback-only status on a rollback to a savepoint, not applying it to the global transaction anymore.
>
> On older versions, the recommended workaround is to switch `globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure` to `false` in such scenarios.

However, even for Spring5, I noticed when reproducing the problem, that the nested transaction may be rolled back, including all things done in the catch block of methodB(). So your recover code might not work inside methodB(), depending on what your recovery looks like. If methodA() was not transactional, that would not happen. Just something to watch out for.

Some more details to be found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/8135

Comment: Interesting. In that link they talk about making refinements to `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` for this, but I didn't see anything relevan in that class compared to my current version. Maybe that's me. Anyway, your answer is sufficient for me, as it confirms this was indeed an unintuitive behavior on Spring part, and not just me being wrong about my assumptions.